# How to loop in array of arrays

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

How to loop in array of arrays. I want to access the `[name]` but I don't know how to start. Please help. I'm using zend framework

```
(
[formdata] => {"profilename":"test"}
[fileUpload] => Array
    (
        [file] => Array
            (
                [name] => 108-thumb_709.jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpg1PQRN
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 62869
            )

    )
 )
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem ? My answer helped ? Thanks for giving me a feddback plz.

Answer (score 0):

This is not relative to zend framework, it's relative to PHP basics.

For loop into a multiple array you can do this :

```
<?php

foreach ($myArray['fileUpload'] as $file) {
    var_dump($file['name']),
}
```

You can take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-foreach-actually-work) And [this PHP manual for foreach](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php)

If you have a structure like this :

```
array(
    1 => array(
        'formdata' => {"profilename":"test"}
        'fileUpload' => array(
            'file' => array(
                'name' => '108-thumb_709.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpg1PQRN',
                'error' => '0',
                'size' => '62869',
            )
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        'formdata' => {"profilename":"test"}
        'fileUpload' => array(
            'file' => array(
                'name' => '108-thumb_709.jpg',
                'type' => 'image/jpeg',
                'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpg1PQRN',
                'error' => '0',
                'size' => '62869',
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

You have to do like this :

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['fileUpload'] as $file) {
        var_dump($file['name']),
    }
}
```